# Why Linq to Entities return more join than necessary

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I want to ask why Linq to Entities return more join than necessary, and way to improve them.

Here is my code:

```
var items = dc.WHItems
        .Select(c => new testModel()
        {
          ID = c.ID,
          Name = c.Name,
          Code = c.Code,
          Discontinued = c.Discontinued,
          Type = c.WHItemType.Name,
          Category = c.WHItemType.WHItemCategory.Name
        })
        .Where(c => c.Discontinued == false)
        .Take(10);
```

Resulting SQL took from SQL Profiler

```
  SELECT TOP (10) 
  [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
  [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
  [Extent1].[Code] AS [Code], 
  [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued], 
  [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name1], 
  [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name2]
  FROM    [dbo].[WHItems] AS [Extent1]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[WHItemTypes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[WHItemTypeID] = [Extent2].[ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WHItemTypes] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[WHItemTypeID] = [Extent3].[ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WHItemCategories] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[WHItemCategoryID] = [Extent4].[ID]
  WHERE 0 = [Extent1].[Discontinued]
```

However using LINQPad4, resulting query satisfied me

```
SELECT TOP (10) [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name], [t0].[Code], [t0].[Discontinued], [t1].[Name] AS [Type], [t2].[Name] AS [Category]
FROM [WHItems] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [WHItemTypes] AS [t1] ON [t1].[ID] = [t0].[WHItemTypeID]
INNER JOIN [WHItemCategories] AS [t2] ON [t2].[ID] = [t1].[WHItemCategoryID]
WHERE NOT ([t0].[Discontinued] = 1)
```

Here is another code, where I try to get items from inventories. Table WHInventories use a composite key on WHItemID and WHID, which I think explained the choice of using 'Inner Join' instead of 'Left Join' as above.

```
  var items = dc.WHInventories
    .Select(c => new testModel()
    {
      ID = c.WHItemID,
      Name = c.WHItem.Name,
      Code = c.WHItem.Code,
      Discontinued = c.WHItem.Discontinued
    })
    .Where(c => c.Discontinued == false)
    .Take(10);
```

Resulting queries in SQL Profiler show additional left outer join. Why would Column Code has to be retrieved from Extent3? while Column Name and Discontinued using the same Extent2

```
  SELECT TOP (10) 
  [Extent1].[WHItemID] AS [WHItemID], 
  [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
  [Extent3].[Code] AS [Code], 
  [Extent2].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
  FROM   [dbo].[WHInventories] AS [Extent1]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[WHItems] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[WHItemID] = [Extent2].[ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[WHItems] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[WHItemID] = [Extent3].[ID]
  WHERE 0 = [Extent2].[Discontinued]
```

If I try explicit join which is means loosing the advantage of having 'Navigation properties'.

```
  var items = dc.WHInventories
    .Join(dc.WHItems, c => c.WHItemID, d => d.ID, (c, d) => new { c, d })
    .Select(c => new testModel()
    {
      ID = c.c.WHItemID,
      Name = c.d.Name,
      Code = c.d.Code,
      Discontinued = c.d.Discontinued
    })
    .Where(c => c.Discontinued == false)
    .Take(10);
```

Resulting Query in SQL Profiler show what I expected. Column Code now using Extent2

```
  SELECT TOP (10) 
  [Extent1].[WHItemID] AS [WHItemID], 
  [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
  [Extent2].[Code] AS [Code], 
  [Extent2].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
  FROM  [dbo].[WHInventories] AS [Extent1]
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[WHItems] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[WHItemID] = [Extent2].[ID]
  WHERE 0 = [Extent2].[Discontinued]
```

Comment: I think the key is in the fact that it's adding left joins.  That means it's saying that the selected values from that joining can be null.  And I'm guessing the sql generation code just doesn't notice that it already has an inner join to the same table.